# Multiple table inheritance and enum entities in Mikro-ORM

Tags: sql, mikro-orm

I have the following entities: Quiz, Slide, TextSlide, and SlideType. A quiz can have multiple slides of different types, such as a TextSlide, a QuestionSlide, etc. I've only included the TextSlide in this example for brevity. The SlideType table acts as a way of storing all Slide types like an enum, but in a proper SQL-way, so with INT ids. The tables look like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE QUIZ (
    id         INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    name       VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    ...
);
```

```sql
CREATE TABLE SLIDE (
    id         INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `index`    INT NOT NULL,
    quiz_id    INT NOT NULL,
    ...
);
```

```sql
CREATE TABLE SLIDE_TEXT (
    slide_id INT          NOT NULL,
    text     VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT SLIDE_TEXT_pk PRIMARY KEY (slide_id),
    CONSTRAINT SLIDE_TEXT_SLIDE_id_fk FOREIGN KEY (slide_id) REFERENCES SLIDE (id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

```sql
CREATE TABLE SLIDE_TYPE (
    id          INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
    code        VARCHAR(32)  NOT NULL,
    name        VARCHAR(64)  NOT NULL,
    description VARCHAR(128) NULL,
    CONSTRAINT SLIDE_TYPE_pk PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

This makes Slide a somewhat abstract class with only three common parameters: id, index, and quiz_id. Implementations like TextSlide and QuestionSlide will all have different fields, but extend from this Slide entity.

How I would solve this in Java with JPA, would be as follows:

```java
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@Table(name = "SLIDE")
public abstract class Slide {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column
    private Integer id;

    // ...

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "slide_type_id")
    private SlideType slideType;

    public Slide(Integer id, /*...*/ SlideType slideType) {
        this.id = id;
        this.slideType = slideType;
    }
}
```

```java
// PersistableEnum is an interface to help with conversion.
@Entity
@Table(name = "SLIDE_TYPE")
public enum SlideType implements PersistableEnum<SlideType, Integer> {
    TEXT(1),
    QUESTION(2);

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "id")
    private final Integer id;

    SlideType(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }
}
```

```java
@Entity
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "slide_id")
@Table(name = "SLIDE_TEXT")
public final class TextSlide extends Slide {
    @Column(nullable = false, length = 255)
    private String text;

    // ...

    public TextSlide(Integer index, /*...*/ String text) {
        super(index, SlideType.TEXT);
        this.text = text;
    }
}
```

However, I can't seem to think of a solution to do this with Mikro-ORM. There are a few challenges:

- enums cannot be used as an entity
- extending Slide with TextSlide causes the TextSlide to inherit Slide's properties, while I actually want TextSlide to be an implementation of the Slide entity where some fields belong to Slide (id, index, quiz_id, ...) and some fields belong to TextSlide (slide_id, text, ...); the reason I want to use one common superclass (Slide), is because then Quiz can eagerly fetch all implementations and I don't have to worry about the types until I need specific properties later on.

Could someone please point me in the right direction? Thanks in advance.

Comment: joined inheritance is unfortunately not supported. here is issue for that https://github.com/mikro-orm/mikro-orm/issues/1575

Comment: Thanks for the link to the issue. Would you be able to help me with a workaround?

Comment: Only thing I can think of is to model it as multiple entities, with FK as PK (https://mikro-orm.io/docs/composite-keys/#use-case-2-simple-derived-identity)

Comment: I guess that could work, but then `Slide` would have to have all optional references to `TextSlide`, `QuestionSlide`, etc., right? That would become a mess... Or would it be possible to reference to an interface?

Comment: Only if you would want to access them from the `Slide` instance (it would be inverse sides). You could work with the implementations (e.g. `TextSlide`) and access the `Slide` properties via their PK.